# No source code is available for type net.sf.json.JSONObject; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am new to GWT.

I have to send a HashMap to GWT server.So i am using JSON.
This Hashmap is a property of file. file is send to server using formpanel.

I created a hidden widget placed it on Form Panel. and Before formpanel.submit i tried to convert this hashmap to String .

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(documentPropertiesToSend);
hidden.setValue(jsonObject.toString());
```

When i run the application it give me an error.

```
**No source code is available for type net.sf.json.JSONObject; did you forget to inherit a required module?**
```

So in gwt.xml file  ,I added this line

```
<inherits name ="net.sf.JSONObject" />
```

now when i run my webApplication i cant see the URL to run it on browser.

How to solve this problem.

Plz help.

Answer (score 2):

GWT 101. And there are already a lot of such "No source code is available" questions on Stack Overflow.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsClient (very first paragraph)

On client-side, use http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.html
(or AutoBeans)